# modbus4j unable to connect

Tags: java, modbus

I am looking for a modbus TCP library for java with the option to select SlaveID. I tried to use the modbus4j library but I can't connect.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the issues details? by providing the errors stack trace, or a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), in order for people here to help you.

Comment: You really don't need SlaveId parameter since what differentiates one slave from another in Modbus/TCP is the IP address.